# if statement combined with jQuery .hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, jquery-hover

I am working with bootstrap and would like to make the drop down menu fade in when in full screen, however when the window size is smaller this dose not look good so I want to turn it off and rely on the basic bootstrap. Here is my code. I cant seem to get the if statement to work.

```
if ($(window).width() > 766){
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeIn(500)}, 
function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeOut(500)
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that jQuery's [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will only select descendants of the `.dropdown` elements from which you're searching

also, the way your jQuery selector for `hover` is written now (with spaces) will cause the binding to apply only to `.dropdown` children of `.navbar`, so the relationship must look like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
        Hovering here shows a menu
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            This is the menu that fades
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```